# Accessing Text Box Values from Form to another class

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, get, set

I have a WPF Application which contains a class called RateView.xaml.cs and MainWindow.xaml.cs

The MainWindow.xaml.cs contains three textboxes of which values I want to pass into the RateView.xaml.cs. The content of these textboxes can be changed by the end user but regardless of that I always want whatever the value is of the textbox to be going into rateview.xaml.cs.

How can this be done?

I am a newbie to coding hence not sure, someone mentioned Get and Set statements, if so how can I do these?

Currently I access my textboxes like this in the MainWindow:

```
private float GetSomeNumber()
{
    bool Number1 = false;
    float parsedNumber1Value = 0.00F;
    Number1 = float.TryParse(Number1_TextBox.Text, out parsedNumber1Value);
    return parsedNumber1Value;
}
```

The GetSomeNumber() method is then passed to another seperate class to do some calculation with.

On intital load it works of the value from my method, but once someone changes the value rateview.xaml.cs doesn't recognise this change and always uses the values that were first loaded.

Thanks

Comment: To access GetSomeNumber from another class it have to be public. So can you show more code, how and where do you call that GetSomeNumber? Also RateView.xaml.cs is filename, and your class name is probably RateView

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `Number1_TextBox` and `Number1_TextBox.Text`?

Comment: @JleruOHeP It is called like so: 'LiveCalculation.Process(GetNumber1());' Passed into a calculation class where some number crunching occurs. However, i need to pass the most current value as it can be changed by the user in the textbox

Answer (score 2):

Just a small example (This is winforms)

This is the mainwindow, where your textbox is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
1
public string TextBox1Text
{ 
  get { return textBox1.Text; }
  set { textBox1.Text = value;
}
}
```

and this is a class where you want to interact with the textboxes:

```
public class Test
{
public Test(Form1 form)
{
//Set the text of the textbox in the form1
form.TextBox1Text = "Hello World";
}
}
```

Comment: Hi TomTom, I am aware of this method in Winforms, however, it doesn't work for WPF.

Comment: Have you anyother way this can be accomplished?

Comment: Take a lookt at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978704/access-controls-properties-from-another-class-in-c-sharp-wpf

Answer (score 1):

To get and set the value of a textbox within another class/form you can do it with something like:

```
public string TextBox1Text
{ get { return textBox1.Text; } 
  set { textBox1.Text = value; } }
```

Comment: Where is this bit of code done? In the MainWindow or in the other class?

Comment: In the MainWindows. There where the textboxes exist.

Comment: And how do i then call them in the other class? I tried using Application.current.mainwindow but they don't appear there?

Comment: You need an instance of the main-window in the other class.

Comment: How do I do this? I tried doing Application.current.mainwindow MW = new Application.current.mainwindow() but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would give the instance of the mainwindow as a parameter to the class. then you cann call the TextBox1Text-Property on the given instance

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how can I do this? This is the class :public partial class RateView : UserControl