# create new class on an existing winform, and access textboxes

Tags: c#

I have created a winform (using the designer VS2016) that has a few methods and events (button clicks) to analyse data.
I have four different ways to analyse the same dataset, my winform currently encompasses one of them and it's working fine.  It's longer than anticipated and before going further i'd like to organise better, so i added a class:

```
namespace Analysis1
{
  public partial class Form1:Form
    private struct DataStruct
    public Form1()
    public void button1_Click //opens the data source and calls methods      
    public class Analyse1:Form1
}
```

however, none of the form textboxes are available in my new class Analyse1 (they are set to "").  I've read quite a few threads ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157133/accessing-text-box-values-from-form-to-another-class)) that seem to imply that i need to initialise every single textbox on the form to use in another class.

there is only one form, is there any way to call all the textbox values from the form into the new class without going one by one?  they are all user entry, and i just need the value, the textboxes don't have any events

thanks

edit: the user will enter a lot of textbox data on the form.  depending on which button they click, it will cause a different type of analysis on the data (and return different charts and tables).  i just want to be able to access
textbox1.Text (and so on, around 120 textboxes)
from each analysis class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's any number of ways you can do that, probably the simplest though, is to use the `tag` property on the various text boxes, something like `Class1`, `Class2`, etc and then expose a property in `Form1` like so;

```
public List<string> Class1Data
{
    get 
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (btn.Tag.ToString().Equals("Class1"))
                result.Add(btn.Text);
        }
        return result; 
    }
}
```

This should make them accessible from `Analyse1`.

And for those who like short, neat code;

```
public List<string> Class1Data
{
    get 
    {
        return Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Tag.ToString().Equals("Class1")).Select(b => b.Text).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to group or loop, as there are over 100 text boxes spread across tab pages, maybe new classes don't make sense in my case

Comment: I've updated the code. That'll return everything in a list for you. You haven't specified what you're after, so that's the best I can do.

Comment: thanks again.  i edited my question, hopefully it's more specific.  how do i access the list if i want textbox1.text vs. textbox2.text?

Comment: A shorter version is `return Controls.OfType<Button>().Select(btn => btn.Text).ToList();`

Comment: Correct. Given the OP's level of knowledge, I opted for the more verbose. I'll update the answer to account for the edited question and include both versions (short/long).

Comment: I still can't access any text. i'm sure i've just done stupid with the code, i can see what it is doing but i don't understand how to access the list

Comment: Well, maybe if you provide the code, we can help out. In the constructor or other method in `Analyse1` it should be as simple as `var myList = Class1Data;` to access it.